# Indexing returns error in Numpy after flatten

Tags: python, numpy, data-analysis

Trying to analyse the numpy indexing of axis after flatten

```
X[np.argwhere(y==0).flatten(),0]
```

From below snippet:

```
def load_pts(csv_name):
    data = np.asarray(pd.read_csv(csv_name, header=None))
    X = data[:,0:2]
    y = data[:,2]

    plt.scatter(X[np.argwhere(y==0).flatten(),0], X[np.argwhere(y==0).flatten(),1],s = 50, color = 'blue', edgecolor = 'k')
    plt.scatter(X[np.argwhere(y==1).flatten(),0], X[np.argwhere(y==1).flatten(),1],s = 50, color = 'red', edgecolor = 'k')

    plt.xlim(-2.05,2.05)
    plt.ylim(-2.05,2.05)
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.tick_params(
        axis='x',
        which='both',
        bottom='off',
        top='off')

    return X,y

X, y = load_pts('data.csv')
plt.show()
```

And it's working:

[image]

Tried the above scenario from NumPy documentation example but getting "Index Out of Bound"

```
x = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
print(x)
print(np.argwhere(x>1))
print("--")
print(x[np.argwhere(x>1).flatten(), 0])
```

Exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-e443d8218694> in <module>()
      3 print(np.argwhere(x>1))
      4 print("--")
----> 5 print(x[np.argwhere(x>1).flatten(), 0])

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

However, the same indexing at axis zero is working in the function load_pts. Unable to understand the axis indexing after flatten at line 6,7 in function load_pts.

[CSV Data File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z6UCcV3OzKRIOZEiKFfgH5KqXXWhuDeG8vXTIKixoHU)

Answer (score 2):

`argwhere().flatten` doesn't make sense:

```
In [100]: x = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [101]: x
Out[101]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
In [102]: x>1
Out[102]: 
array([[False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
In [103]: np.where(x>1)
Out[103]: (array([0, 1, 1, 1]), array([2, 0, 1, 2]))
```

`where` returns an indexing tuple such that: `x[np.where(x>1)]` works

`argwhere` is the transpose of the `where` - an array of the index pairs (for 2d):

```
In [104]: np.argwhere(x>1)
Out[104]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

`flatten` mixes the values from the 2 dimensions

```
In [105]: np.argwhere(x>1).flatten()
Out[105]: array([0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2])
```

The 2's come from findings on the 2nd dimension (size 3), and don't work when applied to the 1st dimension (size 2).

What are you trying to do with this `flatten`?

---

In the larger code snippet, `y` is a 1d array (`data[:,2]`).  There the `argwhere/flatten` works, but is unnecessarily complicated.

```
In [106]: x
Out[106]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
In [107]: y = x[:,1]
In [108]: np.where(y>1)
Out[108]: (array([1]),)       # as single element tuple
In [109]: np.argwhere(y>1)
Out[109]: array([[1]])           # a (1,1) shape array
In [110]: np.argwhere(y>1).flatten()
Out[110]: array([1])             # a (1,) shape array
```

but we get the same thing by simply extracting the one element from the tuple:

```
In [111]: np.where(y>1)[0]
Out[111]: array([1])
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand how flatten works in this X[np.argwhere(y==0).flatten(),0], X[np.argwhere(y==0).flatten(),1]

Comment: edited show how the `y==0` version works, but it unnecessarily complicated.